# Serializing std::string in MFC application

Tags: mfc

I am writing some text which is of `std::string stempstr;`data type into archive object `ar.WriteString(vectorText[i].c_str());` and this i am doing for 10 times by keeping in the for loop where vectorText is a string (i.e. `std::vector<std::string>` 
 vectorText) and this i am doing for 10 times by keeping in the for loop. Now the problem is if i am modifying the text in the vector and again trying to save some additional text is also there along with my required text. please let me know what mistake i am doing why that text is coming while i am saving again. i tried `ar.flush()` also while resaving.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you write a string to the file. Then you modify the string in your code, you write the modified string to the file and you expected it to overwrite the first string instead of appending to it?

Comment: yes.Please let me know how to avoid this problem

Comment: Can you show how you create your CFile?

Comment: BOOL CDocument::OnSaveDocument(LPCTSTR lpszPathName); here in lpszPathName i am giving the folder . that OnSaveDocument is MFC method